# Data Interpretation and Visualisation

Tags: r, statistics, data-visualization

I am trying to fit a Cox Proportional Hazard model using mother's age and infant's gender as covariates.

I am having problems with visually representing the data in R.

I'll post my code so far:

These are my packages:

```
#Getting started:

# load libraries
pkgTest <- function(pkg){
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[,  "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg)) 
    install.packages(new.pkg,  dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg,  require,  character.only = TRUE)
}

lapply(c("survival", "eha", "tidyverse", "ggfortify", "stargazer"),  pkgTest)
```

Here is the data I am using and trying to run a test on:

```
data(infants)

imr <- with(infants, Surv(enter, exit, event))

cox <- coxph(imr ~ sex + age, data = infants)
summary(cox)
drop1(cox, test = "Chisq")
stargazer(cox, type = "text")


cox_fit <- survfit(cox)
autoplot(cox_fit)

newdat <- with(infants, 
               data.frame(
                 sex = c("male", "female"), age="Age"
               )
)

plot(survfit(cox, newdata = newdat), xscale = 12,
     conf.int = T,
     ylim = c(0.6, 1),
     col = c("red", "blue"),
     xlab = "Time",
     ylab = "Survival proportion",
     main = "")
legend("bottomleft",
       legend=c("Male", "Female"),
       lty = 1, 
       col = c("red", "blue"),
       text.col = c("red", "blue"))

# Adding an interaction
cox.int <- coxph(imr ~ sex * age, data = infants)
summary(cox.int)
drop1(cox.int, test = "Chisq")
stargazer(cox.int, type = "text")

plot(survfit(cox.int, newdata = newdat), xscale = 12,
      conf.int = T,
      ylim = c(0.6, 1),
      col = c("male", "female"),
      xlab = "Age",
      ylab = "Survival proportion",
      main = "")
```

any advice on this would be most helpful! I can't figure out what I am doing wrong in generating a graph from the final data.

Comment: What are you trying to do with newdat? Rename the column names and levels of age and sex?

Comment: Yes. Is that wrong?

Comment: And the second plot should have female and male as two different curves (strata)?

Comment: That's the idea. (I'm totally butchering this--lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the impact of sex on survival probability, rename the sex levels in your `newdat` according to the sex levels in `infants`. Age is fixed to their average value, repeated for the number of different sex levels.

**Code**

```
data(infants)

imr <- with(infants, Surv(enter, exit, event))

cox <- coxph(imr ~ sex + age, data = infants)

cox_fit <- survfit(cox)

newdat <- with(infants, 
               data.frame(
                 sex = c("girl", "boy"), age=rep(mean(age, na.rm = TRUE), 2)))

plot(survfit(cox, newdata = newdat), xscale = 12,
     conf.int = T,
     ylim = c(0.6, 1),
     col = c("red", "blue"),
     xlab = "Time",
     ylab = "Survival proportion",
     main = "")
legend("bottomleft",
       legend=c("Male", "Female"),
       lty = 1, 
       col = c("red", "blue"),
       text.col = c("red", "blue"))
```

**Output**

[image]

---

I recommend using `ggsurvplot` instead, which allows for more customization:

```
ggsurvplot(survfit(cox, newdata = newdat), data = infants,
       legend.labs = c("Male", "Female"),
       legend.title = "Sex")
```

[image]